# NSTableView selectRowIndexes does not throw event

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6

I try to change my row selection on a NSTableView in a OSX-App.
I do it like:

```
tableview.selectRowIndexes(NSIndexSet(index: currentIndex - 1), byExtendingSelection: false)
```

The row gets selected *visually* but I do not get the event (Sent Action). If I click on it with the mouse, the event works.
Any suggestions? THX

Comment: That's just how it works. Controls send their action as a response to user manipulation, not programmatic changes. Since you, the programmer, are manipulating the table view's selection, you can also invoke whatever side effects you think that should have. In other words, invoke the action method yourself (or do the work the action method would do) after changing the selection.

Comment: I'm used to iOS programming, which I thought should have similar behavior, as both are from Apple. When I select a row in a UITableview programmatically  the corresponding methods gets called.

Comment: You can set a delegate for the table view and have it implement `-tableViewSelectionDidChange:`. That will be called even for programmatic changes of the selection.